# How do i wait for all threads in java code here?

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to compare thread performance on solaris/linux/windows 64 bit JVM's, with the below code.

I personally, prefer this style of coding for threading, because you have a method performing some computation and you would like to run that computation on separate thread. It does not look intuitive for me launch an object using Thread class. So, Please suggest me for alternate code style, on same lines(if required).

```
public class Dummy2 {

    private static int NUM_OF_THREADS=100000;

    public void loopSomeTime() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                int count = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        long beginTime = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i =0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS ; i++){
            Dummy2 d = new Dummy2();
            d.loopSomeTime();
        }
        //I need to wait here
        long endTime = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
        System.out.println(endTime/(1000*1000) + "milliseconds");
    }
}
```

How do i wait for all threads to complete before the computation of  `endTime` in MainThread?

Note: I am java beginner and learning Java threads

Comment: Did you even bohtehr to Google?

Comment: If you change this to use Java 5+ concurrency, this problem becomes a lot easier. Hint: [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Comment: @Mawg i see many answers on SO for `join()`, but they are not helpful

Comment: Hint, the answer has little or nothing to do with Java and mall or all to do with threading in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of all of the threads and call `join` on each one.

```
public class Test {

    private static int NUM_OF_THREADS = 100000;
    // Keep track of my thread.
    private Thread thread;

    public void loopSomeTime() {
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }

    public void waitToFinish() throws InterruptedException {
        thread.join();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Test> loopers = new ArrayList<>();
        long beginTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            Test d = new Test();
            d.loopSomeTime();
            // Keep track of all loopers.
            loopers.add(d);
        }
        //I need to wait here
        for (Test t : loopers) {
            t.waitToFinish();
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
        System.out.println(endTime / (1000 * 1000) + "milliseconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: i like your coding style. Additionally i would like to say, coming from C background, it looks weird for me to see code like `class SubClass extends Thread{} SubClass obj = new SubClass(); obj.start();` because i think multithreading has nothing to do with OOPS paradigm. So, i wrote `loopSomeTime()` method first and placed its computation in thread, Do you think this approach looks good?

Comment: @overexchange - Your approach looks fine - however, creating thousands of threads is not usually a good thing. You would normally use a [Thread Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Comment: i know creating of thread resource on-demand takes more time than completing the execution of that thread. There is nothing to learn about ThreadPool, except using it or write your own.

Comment: i would like to chat with you on this style of coding: `class SubClass extends Thread{} SubClass obj = new SubClass(); obj.start();` can u invite me?

Comment: Another point, what if `loopSomeTime()` was a static method, how would i track the threads?

Answer (score 2):

The key here is you need some way to wait for all of the threads to complete. However, threads are low-level constructs that are a pain to manage correctly.

Using higher-level constructs, you can push some of the tricky dirty work into the Java framework and focus on what you are trying to do: waiting for the threads to complete.

Here is some Java that illustrates the overall design I recommend. It is not complete, but should be a good start.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int threads = 1000;
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    List<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();

    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
      futures.add(exec.submit(makeTask()));
    }

    while (!futures.isEmpty()) {
      Iterator<Future<?>> it = futures.iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().isDone()) {
          it.remove();
        }
      }
    }

    final long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    // TODO: report the difference.
  }

  private static Runnable makeTask() {
    // TODO: return a Runnable that does stuff.
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: i would not like to read these words `ExecutorService` `Future` with the level of knowledge i have about java threads. thank you

Comment: @overexchange it really does make it simpler, you focus on tasks and results instead of nitty-gritty thread details. All of the tricky, error-prone code is encapsulated by the concurrency framework.

Comment: @overexchange Learn in the way that is easiest to understand for you, though afterwards, learn this approach.  It is Java's way of Thread pooling, and you will begin to see this approach used more and more often as time passes.

Comment: my point is, In multi threading, Everything boils down to  `a set of computation` to make it run on a separate jvm thread that gets mapped to LWP of OS, to get scheduled. Additionally, for this you may need some synchronisation facilities to ensure integrity of that computation. If there is a bigger picture than this in enterprise app development, then i need to learn that. It is to just use threadpool there is nothing to learn there about it.